# Compile error when attemping to get value of QSqlQuery?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

Just trying to mess around with Qt and SQLite to get familiar with how things work- I haven't really done DB programming since my vb6 days, so please be easy ;]

I'm just trying to get the result of a query and I'm trying to follow some examples I found online (namely [this](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/CS001507_-_Searching_for_data_in_a_database_in_Qt) one). The process seems simple enough: create the QSqlQuery object, have it execute a query, check that something came back, and just get the value. When doing this, I'm getting an error. Code follows:

```
bool DatabaseManager::structureDB(){
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.exec("CREATE TABLE mytable"
                      " (id integer primary key,"
                      " firstname varchar(20),"
                      " lastname varchar(20),"
                      " age integer)");

    QSqlQuery query2;
    query2.exec("pragma table_info(mytable)");

    if(query2.first()){
        QString test = query2.value(0).toString(); // Error line
        qDebug()<<test;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct QVariant'
```

On the line commented above. I'm not sure what this error means or what I'm doing wrong, can someone please help? Thanks so much!

Comment: Is `QVariant` defined? (Have you included its header?)

Comment: I did not include it, I have included <QSqlQuery>. Including <QVariant> seems to have done the trick, thanks! If you submit a formal answer I'll select it as correct, I think you get a cupcake or something if you answer correctly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the type is declared but not defined, like this:

```
struct QVariant;
```

Once you try to use it, it needs to be defined, like this:

```
struct QVariant
{
    // stuff goes here
};
```

The error is telling you it's *incomplete* (declared but not defined), and therefore not usable. You should include the header `<QVariant>` to get the definition of `QVariant`, to make it *complete* and therefore usable.